# Show Status Bar Notification with MonoDroid C#

Tags: c#, android, notifications, xamarin.android

How can I show a status bar notification with MonoDroid using C#?

Can someone give me an example?

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

You want to use [Android.App.Notification](http://docs.monodroid.net/index.aspx?link=T:Android.App.Notification) and [Android.App.NotificationManager](http://docs.monodroid.net/index.aspx?link=T:Android.App.NotificationManager), for example from [LocalService.ShowNotification()](https://github.com/mono/monodroid-samples/blob/master/ApiDemo/App/LocalService.cs#L56):

```
// within some Android.Content.Context subclass (Activity, Service, etc.)
void ShowNotification ()
{
    IEnumerable<char> text = GetText (Resource.String.local_service_started);
    var notification = new Notification (Resource.Drawable.stat_sample, 
            text, 
            System.Environment.TickCount);
    PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.GetActivity (this, 0, 
            new Intent (this, typeof (LocalServiceActivities.Controller)), 
            0);
    notification.SetLatestEventInfo (this, 
            GetText (Resource.@string.local_service_label), 
            text, 
            contentIntent);
    var nm = (NotificationManager) GetSystemService (NotificationService);
    nm.Notify (Resource.String.local_service_started, notification);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can see below link, and like page to see more:
https://www.facebook.com/pages/M%C3%A3-Ngu%E1%BB%93n/371039113001844

Answer (score 0):

Try PushSharp:
https://github.com/Redth/PushSharp

It worked great for me.